# Exists clause in criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Consider this query:

```
select user_id
from user_role a
where a.role_id = -1
      and not exists (select 1 
                      from user_role b 
                      where b.role_id != a.role_id 
                            and b.user_id = a.user_id);
```

I'm trying to recreate it using gorm criterias. Is it possible? How can I add the exists clause?

**UPDATE**

I've been trying to resolve this way:

```
UserRole.createCriteria().list{
  eq('role', roleObj)
  createAlias('user', 'u')
  not{
    inList('u.id', {
      not {
        eq('role', roleObj)
      }
      projections {
       property 'user.id'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Still not working. I'm gettins this error when executing it:

```
DUMMY$_closure1_closure2_closure3_closure4 cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I don't understand the error message. The inner criteria returns the list of ids and if I replace the inner criteria with a list of longs it works. Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested : Try Sql restriction

```
 UserRole.createCriteria().list {
  and{
    eq('roleId',-1)
    sqlRestriction(" not exists(select 1 
                        from UserRole  b 
                        where ............ 
                              )")
  }
```

}

-- Hoping you have named your domain as UserRole and column name named as roleId.

Comment: I guess that will work. But could it be done without using sqlRestriction or HQL? I would prefer to use a simplest solution if possible.

Comment: Any other way..am afraid havn't tried out.I mostly end up using hql or sqlRestriction and sometimes native queries.Share if you find any.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ..I learnt something today:).The inner closure returns the list of ids of type object userRole and the inList expects it to be list of Long.So you passing the List<Long> explicitly resolves the issue.

Comment: def holdLongIds  = [];
UserRole.createCriteria().list{
eq('role', roleObj)
   createAlias('user', 'u')
   not{
    
    inList('u.id', {not {eq('role', roleObj) } projections {  property 'user.id'}}.each{ obj -> 
          holdLongIds.collect { obj.id }
          })
    } 
   }

Comment: Again not tested just a rough workout.Hope it helps.

Comment: Checking HibernateCriteriaBuilder code it seems that this way of doing sub-queries is only available for single value operators (eq, gt, ge, etc). For multiple value operators (in, inList) it is expecting to receive a Collection.

So, I think that finally I will go for sqlRestriction or HQL solutions.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Nope, you can use detached criteria subqueries even for in, inlist etc